# what are the ways to call user defined function in side Stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

using select statement we can call functions inside the stored procedure, is there another ways to call functions inside the stored procedure.

Comment: Functions (table- or scalar-valued) can be called inside stored procedures in exactly the same ways as they are inside batch statements; there are no limitations. Perhaps you could consider providing some more detail in your question about exactly what you're trying to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getdate()` you can call inside a proc

```
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Procedure (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the procedure.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    declare @date datetime

   set @date= getdate()
END
GO
```

Comment: we can call functions using select statement, but i want know the other ways to call function apart from using select statement.

Comment: answer is edited.If you are looking for something else let me know

Comment: is only these two methods to call function?

Answer (score 0):

try

SET @yourvariable = yourfunctionname('your params');

Answer (score 0):

> **Function**

create function fn_FunctionSum(@Number1 int , @Number2 int)
returns int
as
begin
declare @result int
select @result = @Number1 + @Number2;
return @result
end

> **Store Procedure**

create proc sp_Sum(@first int, @second int )
as
begin

```
 -------Call Function in store procedure ------
select [dbo].[fn_FunctionSum](@first, @second)
```

end
execute sp_Sum 2,5